# Problems with Copy and assignment constructor

Tags: c++, deep-copy

I have the following code, used as a part of a Linked List:

```
// copy constructor:
LinkedList<T>(const LinkedList<T> &list) 
{
    // make a deep copy
    for (LinkedList<T>::Iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++)
    {
        add(*i);
    }
}


// assignment constructor
LinkedList<T>& operator= (const LinkedList<T> &list) 
{
    // make a deep copy
    for (LinkedList<T>::Iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++)
    {
        add(*i);
    }
}
```

But when I compile I get the following errors (this is when I use it as an assignment constructor):

```
1>------ Build started: Project: AnotherLinkedList, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\users\ra\source\repos\sandbox\container\anotherlinkedlist\linkedlist.h(57): error C2662: 'LinkedList<int>::Iterator LinkedList<int>::begin(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const LinkedList<int>' to 'LinkedList<int> &'
1>c:\users\ra\source\repos\sandbox\container\anotherlinkedlist\linkedlist.h(57): note: Conversion loses qualifiers
1>c:\users\ra\source\repos\sandbox\container\anotherlinkedlist\linkedlist.h(55): note: while compiling class template member function 'LinkedList<int> &LinkedList<int>::operator =(const LinkedList<int> &)'
1>c:\users\ra\source\repos\sandbox\container\anotherlinkedlist\main.cpp(20): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'LinkedList<int> &LinkedList<int>::operator =(const LinkedList<int> &)' being compiled
1>c:\users\ra\source\repos\sandbox\container\anotherlinkedlist\main.cpp(14): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'LinkedList<int>' being compiled
1>c:\users\ra\source\repos\sandbox\container\anotherlinkedlist\linkedlist.h(57): error C2662: 'LinkedList<int>::Iterator LinkedList<int>::end(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const LinkedList<int>' to 'LinkedList<int> &'
1>c:\users\ra\source\repos\sandbox\container\anotherlinkedlist\linkedlist.h(57): note: Conversion loses qualifiers
1>Done building project "AnotherLinkedList.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The iterator code for begin and end looks like this:

```
// get root
    Iterator begin()
    {
        return Iterator(sp_Head);
    }

    // get end
    Iterator end()
    {
        return Iterator(nullptr);
    }
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: FYI -- Your assignment operator does not remove the old list and fails to return a value.

Comment: True, but that's not the reason for the compilation error. The compilation error is because begin/end are not const class methods, and they must be. Free karma to whoever wants it...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: i see your point. of course i need to delete all the existing items in the list, add the new one, and return *this (correct?)

Comment: You could do that, but using [copy / swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) is better.

Comment: `Iterator(nullptr)` <-- this looks like a problem waiting to happen. Will the iterator always point to a nullptr at the end?

Comment: @JHBonarius: i will point to the node after the tail node in the list, which allways should be nullptr. since i keep track of the tail node, then i could use sp_Tail->p_Next

Comment: Now my copy constructor works perfectly. I had the problem, that i kept running around with the original list, until i figured out, that the head and tail pointers was declared as static *DOH*. So now i just need my assignment operator to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, it would seem that your `LinkedList` does not have variants of `begin()` and `end()` that can be called on a const object. The parameters to your copy constructor and assignment operator are const, however. You will have to add const versions of `begin()` and `end()`.

Presumably, you're looking for something like this:

```cpp
    ConstIterator begin() const { Iterator(sp_Head); }
    Iterator begin() { Iterator(sp_Head); }

    ConstIterator end() const { ConstIterator(nullptr); }
    Iterator end() { Iterator(nullptr); }
```

Where `ConstIterator` is a version of your iterator type that iterates over const elements…

Comment: Should i add methods that returns const ? I have tried to add change them to const Iterator, but with the same result

Comment: @tannic read the error "Conversion loses qualifiers" the member function has to be const qualified.

Comment: @tannic If you have a const list, then that usually means that the content of the list is to be logically const, i.e., someone with a `const LinkedList<T>&` should not be able to modify the content of the list. If you return a const iterator, that just means the iterator itself cannot be modified. What you usually want is for begin and end on a const list to return iterators that iterate over `const T` rather than `T`…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel so need to make a ConstIterator class, that should (allmost) be a copy of my current Iterator ?

Comment: @tannic I tend to make the iterator a class template, `template<typename Type> class iterator_impl { using value_type = Type; ... };` and after the iterator class template definition just do `using iterator = iterator_impl<T>; using const_iterator = iterator_impl<T const>;` to get both.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: did as you suggested, and it worked perfect. thx.