# Move constructor vs. Move assignment

Tags: c++, move-assignment-operator

As an extension to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942117) question, i am trying to get my move assignment correct.

I have the following code:

```
// copy assignment operator
LinkedList<T>& operator= (LinkedList<T> other) noexcept
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}

// move assignment operator
LinkedList<T>& operator= (LinkedList<T>&& other) noexcept
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

But when i try to use it, my code fails to compile.

First some code:

```
LinkedList<int> generateLinkedList()
{
    LinkedList<int> List;   
    List.add(123);
    return List;
}


int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> L;   
    L = generateLinkedList();
      ^ get an error here...
```

I get the following error:

> main.cpp(24): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
>
> linkedlist.h(79): note: could be 'LinkedList &LinkedList::operator =(LinkedList &&) noexcept'(Points to the move assignment operator)
>
> linkedlist.h(63): note: or       'LinkedList &LinkedList::operator =(LinkedList) noexcept' (Points to the copy assignment operator)
>
> main.cpp(24): note: while trying to match the argument list '(LinkedList, LinkedList)'

Are my move assignment operator wrong, or do i use it the wrong way?

Comment: Good explanation in the C++11 section of the first answer to [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). Might even be good enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The copy assignment operator would take a `const LinkedList<T>& other`, not a `LinkedList<T> other`.

This

```
LinkedList<T>& operator= (LinkedList<T> other) noexcept
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

is how one would implement both copy and move assignment at once using [copy-and-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). By re-using the copy and move constructors (`other` is either copy-constructed or move-constructed), and you just swap `this` with `other`. `other` dies at the end of the function, taking with it the old state of `this`. This implementation is totally fine, but then you don't need a second overload for temporaries (which is indeed ambiguous).

If you want to provide separate copy assignment operators for copy vs move assignment, the signatures would be

```
// copy assignment operator
LinkedList<T>& operator=(const LinkedList<T>& other) noexcept
{
  //...
}

// move assignment operator
LinkedList<T>& operator=(LinkedList<T>&& other) noexcept
{
  //...
}
```

But since you already have `swap` and the copy+move constructors, using copy-and-swap is preferable.

PS: As these appear to be inline definitions (i.e. within the class body), you can skip the `<T>` template argument - within the `LinkedList` template class definition, writing `LinkedList` automatically refers to the "current instantiation" (i.e. `LinkedList<T>`).

Comment: Now i have updated the copy assignment operator to receive a const LinkedList<T>&. Now that wont compile. I was following the examples in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543)

Comment: @tannic Sorry, I originally meant to remove the bodies in the second code snippet as they wouldn't make sense. Indeed, you cannot swap with a `const LinkedList&` (because it's `const`) - you'd have to construct a copy manually first (i.e. `LinkedList copy(other); swap(*this, copy); return *this;`), but that's better done by doing copy-and-swap the normal way.

Comment: Didn't know about this trick. I use `operator=(other)` in implementing the move constructor though.

Comment: @TanveerBadar If you already have `swap` for your type, you can just implement the move constructor as default-constructor + `swap(*this, other)` (but maybe there's a more efficient implementation - default-constructing and then swapping some plain `int` value is wasted effort, you might as well copy it in the first place).

Comment: @MaxLanghof: if i looks in the link above (copy/swap paradime), i see this codesnip, which was actually what i used: `dumb_array& operator=(dumb_array other) // (1)
{
    swap(*this, other); // (2)

    return *this;
}`

Comment: @tannic Yes, when you do it that way you simply don't need an `LinkedList&&` overload for `operator=` anymore. Is there still something unclear?

Comment: @MaxLanghof: ah of course. I didnt read it properly. The copy and move assignment operator would be the same, right ?